# Prove that an initial value problem has more than 1 solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

let $y' = \sin{\sqrt{|y|}}$, I need to prove that there is more than one solution with the initial value $y(0) = 0$, and I was given guidance to use $y = z^2$, reach $z'=f(x, z)$ and use the existence and uniqueness theorem to find a solution for $z'=f(x, z)$, with it I'm suppose to prove the existence of a second solution.

the first solution is easy to find $y \equiv 0$ is a solution. But I'm not sure how to find the second even with the guidence, here is what I tried:

Using the guidance I say
$$
y = z^2 \Longrightarrow y' = 2z \cdot z' \Longrightarrow 2z\cdot z' = \sin{\sqrt{|z^2|}} = \sin{z} \Longrightarrow z' = \frac{\sin{z}}{2z}
$$

Because $\frac{\sin{z}}{2z}$ is continuous and $\frac{\partial}{dz}\frac{\sin{z}}{2z}$ is also continuous when $z\neq 0$ from the existence and uniqueness theorem I get that there is a solution $u(x)$ for $z' = \frac{\sin{z}}{2z}$ and a point $(x_0, z_0)$ ($z_0 \neq 0$), so I create a new function $v(x)$ where $v(0) = 0$ and $v(x) = u^2(x)$ for $x\neq 0$, $v$ is a solution for $y' = \sin{\sqrt{|y|}}$, and it upholds the initial value. Because it doesn't uphold the existence and uniqueness theorem 's requirements there is no contradictions with having 2 solution to the same initial value problem

Though my solution seems good to me I feel like something is missing, but I can't put a finger on it

**EDIT**:

I'm was told to work with $y = z^2$, I understand that the solution to the IVP should look like $$
v(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } x \leq 0 \\
  u^2(x) & \mbox{if } x > 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
where $u(x)$ is a solution for $z' = \frac{\sin{z}}{2z}$. $u(x)\not\equiv 0$ because $0$ isn't a solution for $z$, so $v(x) \not\equiv 0$ but I don't know how I can prove that $v(x)$ is derivable

Comment: There is one solution that "immediately moves as you go in either direction", which is the one that you get from separating variables. It is implicitly described by $\int_0^y \frac{d\tilde{y}}{\sin(\sqrt{\tilde{y}})} = x$. There are other solutions that first budge from $y=0$ at a different time, or (as you noticed) never budge at all. This is easier to write down to develop intuition with $y'=\sqrt{y}$ instead, but the behavior is really the same near $y=0$.

Comment: Without trying it I am not sure whether this suggestion to play with $y=z^2$ helps you any.

Comment: @Ian so If I understand correctly, my answer is good but there are simpler ways to find another solution?

Comment: Now that I think about it, $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$ is a solution, thus $y = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$ is also a solution for ODE, so if I define a new function $v(x)$, such that $v(0) = 0$ and $v(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$ for $x \neq 0$, $v(x)$ is a solution for the initial value problem and it doesn't contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem because $v(x)$ is not continuous in any area around $(0, 0)$

Comment: A solution to an IVP is is differentiable by definition and thus is also continuous by definition. So no, jumping between squares of zeros of $\sin$ doesn't give you the non-uniqueness. It is really exactly the same as the situation with $y'=|y|^{1/2}$ even though that only has one zero.

Comment: Basically I think what I said is easier than going via this $z$.

Comment: my professor is insisted on using $y=z^2$. I think I get the main idea here, the answer to the IVP is a new function$v(x)$ where $v(x)=0, x \le 0$, $v(x) = u^2(x), x >0$  and $u(x)$ is a solution for $z$, but now I have the problem of proving that $v(x)$ is derivable for $x=0$ and that $v(x)$ isn't $y\equiv 0$

Comment: You can not just simple remove the absolute value, the equation you get should be $z'=\frac{\sin(|z|)}{2z}$. This means that at the initial point $z'=\pm\frac12$ has two different possible values. After moving away from the zero axis, the sign remains constant. Also consider that the solution can remain some time on the axis and branch off in the explored fashion at a later time.

Comment: @LutzLehmann but $z \neq 0$ that means that the solution can't pass through a point $(x, 0)$ because $y(x)=0=z^2(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on
$$
z'=\frac{\sin(|z|)}{2z}
$$
for $z\ne 0$, you can consider the ODEs
$$
z'=\pm f(z)~~\text{ where }~~f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(z)}{2z},&z\ne 0\\\frac12,&z=0\end{cases}
$$
As you observed, $f(z)$ has a nice power series expansion, so satisfies the conditions of the existence-and-uniqueness theorem.

Solutions of $z'=f(z)$ give solutions of the original ODE whenever $z\ge0$, and those of $z'=-f(z)$ whenever $z\le0$. Both variants give a solution each for $x\ge 0$ that passes through $z(0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I was missing, with power series I can prove the derivative is also continuous